# How to calculate directly with VBA in Table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate directly in Excel.

Steps:
-Make new table without duplicates from Table1(Dates)
-Get the headers from the values in Done
-Sum if date and name are equal

Here an example of the solution with a formula.

[image]

I know hot to solve this with `cFormula` but i couldnt find a fast and "easy to code" solutiuon directly with vba.

```
Dim sbl As ListObject: Set sbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(4).ListObjects("Tab_1") 'source table
Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(4).ListObjects("Tab_2") 'target table


MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(sbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange, sbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange)


End Sub
```

I got his. But i couldnt find otu how to write in the column "Peter"

Can someone help me plz or give me an information.

Comment: This result is a simple Pivot Table with aggregation by Count. If you record a macro as you create it, you will have a VBA solution.

Comment: With the Macro i get an cFormula solution. I am looking for a solution with WorksheetFunction.

Comment: Why do you need to use `WorksheetFunction`? There may be a simpler solution for your needs. Also what version of Excel are you running?  Certain useful functions are only available in Office 365.

Comment: I am using Office2016. Maybe you are right. I want to have this as  a snippet so i can use it like a toolbox for other workbooks too.

Comment: To create a "toolbox" snippet, I would suggest using VBA arrays and Dictionaries to create a custom function that creates a pivot table like structure but outputs a VBA array.

Comment: Can you give me a link to an example plz.

Comment: Sorry. I don't have any links to examples. But if you want to write something up, I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, hope it fits your need!

[image]

```
Sub AddFormulaAndCopyToValues2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim sbl As ListObject: Set sbl = ws.ListObjects("Tab_1")    'source table
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Tab_2")    'target table
    
    Dim tblRow As Integer: tblRow = tbl.Range.Row               ' first row
    Dim tblCol As Integer: tblCol = tbl.Range.Column            ' first Column
    
    Dim dateRng As Range: Set dateRng = sbl.ListColumns("Date").DataBodyRange
    Dim doneRng As Range: Set doneRng = sbl.ListColumns("Done").DataBodyRange
    
    ' set rng to insert formula
    Dim frmRng As Range: Set frmRng = tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Resize(tbl.ListRows.Count, 3)
        
    ' set rng to insert formula
    Dim rCell As Range: Set rCell = tbl.HeaderRowRange(2, 2)
    
    ' Do calculations
    Dim dateVal As Variant
    Dim nameVal As String
    For Each rCell In frmRng
        dateVal = Cells(rCell.Row, tblCol).Value
        nameVal = Cells(tblRow, rCell.Column).Value
        rCell.Formula2R1C1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(dateRng, dateVal, doneRng, nameVal)
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is working but I am looking for a solution which is not depending on the position of the Table like ````RC6, R2C````. I am trying to get a solution without the position. Found something with ````subtable```` but couldnt find out how to get it done. Maybe you have an idea :)